# useEffect not re-rendering on route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**States**

```
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [URL, SetURL] = useState<URL | String>();
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
```

**resetSearch Function**

```
  const resetSearch = () => {
    setSearchTerm("");
    setSearchResults([]);
    inputRef.current.value = ""
  }
```

**ResetQuery Function**

```
  const resetSearchQueryOnRouteChange = () => {
    SetURL(window.location.href)
    if (window.location.href != URL) {
      resetSearch();
    }
  }
```

**useEffect**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    resetSearchQueryOnRouteChange()
  }, [window.location.href, URL])
```

The issue is that i need the the `resetSearchQueryOnRouteChange()` function to be run on every route render, but when i change routes the function is not called, but the function itself is fully functional.

**How can i make the function run when i change route/url?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using 'react-router' each location change will trigger whole re-render of the page. So, this block of code wouldn't execute.
You need to start to use 'react-router' [and you'll get access to location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location)